# Update your Stripe secret config from sk_test to sk_live

Tags: ios, google-cloud-functions, stripe-payments

I have an app that uses stripe payments and I am trying to allow users' cards to be charged. I have successfully changed the pk_test to pk_live but I am having issues changing sk_test to sk_live. I had paid someone to install stripe for me, and the only reference I can see to sk is inside of node.js as

```
const stripe = require('stripe')(functionConfig().stripesecretkeys.key);
```

This leads me to believe that the individual used terminal to reference the sk_test. My question is, how can I change this to be live instead of test.

I see this on firebase Doc,

```
firebase functions:config:set stripe.secret=<YOUR STRIPE LIVE SECRET KEY>
```

EDIT:

I have managed to add the secret key in through terminal, but when I create a new customer they are still being created under test mode on stripe? am I missing something?

Comment: Try following the instructions here: https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/tree/master/stripe#deploy-and-test

Comment: thanks for your suggestion @PaulAsjes. I have done this yet, the customers are still being created in test mode instead of live mode.

Comment: I have depoloyed the functions, re ran my app and created a new user still same thing. My publishableKeys have all been updated with pk_live as well as sk_live